# How to reconstruct MMW image using electrical field in each direction at Receiver points using Back projection algorithm

Tags: image-processing, matlab, python, reconstruction

I have used a structure including 109 Receivers and 4 transmitters in order to do MMW imaging(multistatic imaging). Imaging was done in 3 different frequencies. So, now I have electrical field in each direction at each receiver point resulted from each transmitter at those frequencies. I just want to know how can I implement it in matlab or python.
Can you give me a step-by-step guideline, sample code or document for implementation?
Actually, this is the best article I found in this subject, But i can not understand its implementation perfectly:

"Walk-through millimeter wave imaging testbed
based on double multistatic cross arrays"

Here is the link to the available data:

[nearfield data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k1pyp4LvzBPAo5wf6O2omFKrfwU8FxK0/view?usp=sharing)

actually I found some manuals especially the one available in [this link](https://www.clear.rice.edu/elec431/projects96/DSP/bpanalysis.html). But some concepts in [this link](https://www.clear.rice.edu/elec431/projects96/DSP/bpanalysis.html) (like "rotation") are not mentioned in the previous article. also, some concepts like "wavenumber" and "the number of transmitters" are not discussed in [this link](https://www.clear.rice.edu/elec431/projects96/DSP/bpanalysis.html). I am a little confused.